# What font has this weird H?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

Can anyone tell me what font this is? I have looked everywhere and I can't find it. I tried some of the websites for finding the font in an image but they all get it wrong. The "H" is what I have been going by for the font. I need it for the CSS.

[image: CHADDOCK]

Tried:
What Font Is
WhatTheFont!

I would just use photoshop but I don't have a license.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've found is Hurme Geometric Sans.

It's not perfect but it's dam near close.

[image]

Comment: Care to comment why the downvote?

Comment: That doesn't have the characteristic dropped A and H bars, true they could have customised those but there are still tell-tale differences, and there are other fonts (like Neutraface as pointed out) that seem to match better.

Comment: They are 100% added to the font. It was suggested in previous comments so I didn't think I needed to reiterate that.

Answer (score 0):

Chaddock logo has a patent paid by them. So if they had this logo created by an artist, chances are its a Vectored font not a basic font you can download elsewhere. So suggestion would be just retrace the whole logo in Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop, or whichever software you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a custom design, it might have started out as a regular font, but has been edited.

You can use the free vector image editing software Inkscape(dot)org to type some letter forms, turn them into outlines using Path > Object to Path, then modify the outlines as you want by adding additional anchors.

Photoshop isn't so useful for this kind of thing anyway. Adobe's vector image editor is Illustrator, which also isn't free.

Example editing the crossbar of the A by adding additional anchor points in Inkscape:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a modified version of Neutraface.